# Does this docker image support bind mounts : mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-1903

Tags: docker, .net-core-3.1

I have built a .net core 3.1 console app that processes files that get dumped into a folder. I have put the app into a docker container and all works fine except when I try to bind mount the containers working folder to a folder in the host.

So this works fine:

docker run --name xmlprocessor-container -i xmlprocessor-windows-image

I can see from the docker console output it is running and waiting for files

This breaks:

docker run -v e:/Logging:c:/app --name xmlprocessor-container -i xmlprocessor-windows-image

[image]

The error is meaningless and not related at all. I have used sql server in docker containers and used bind mounts successfully to attach databases etc. So I'm fairly sure the command I'm using is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found a solution. c:\app in the container is where the actual code has been deployed. Trying to bind mount this folder to a host folder is an issue and results in the above bizarre error message. If I try to bind mount to any other folder it works fine

So this works:

docker run -v e:/Logging:c:/files --name xmlprocessor-container -i xmlprocessor-windows-image

The files I drop in are processed as expected. As for the strange error... that cost me a good 4 hours of my time.